# Root raised cosine parameter

Tags: matlab, filters, bpsk

I try to create matched filter for receive BPSK signal. Sampling rate of the signal is 228000 Hz, data rate 1187.5 symbols/sec, signal was shaped using root raised cosine filter with rolloff factor = 1.

I cant get what should be *sps — Samples per symbol* in function [rcosdesign](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/rcosdesign.html) . First i thought it's 228000/1187.5 , but tried it and probably I'm wrong...

Answer (score 1):

No, you're right. It wants to know how many samples you have for each symbol in the BPSK stream. This is the ratio of the sample rate to the symbol rate.

Comment: Is this correct output of the matched filter? https://i.imgur.com/B6MnLk4.jpg